# Vilna Gaon -- mini nevuah after six hours of study?

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, nevua-prophecy, vilna-gaon

In *Aish Moharan*<sup>1</sup>, Rav Berland cites the Vilna Gaon as having said that after six hours of uninterrupted Torah study, the first thoughts a person has are a form of mini *nevuah* (prophecy).

> כמו שמובא מהגאון מוילנא שאחרי שש שעות למוד תורה בלי הפסק, המחשבה הראשונה שתבוא לך כמו נבואה מהשמים, וזה בדוק ומנוסה

What is the source for this idea, and where can it be found in the writings of the Vilna Gaon?

---

<sup>1. Part 1, Torah 1</sup>

Comment: why not ask him?

Comment: https://ravberland.com/contact/ @ray

Comment: I was going to just give his gabbai a call, but it seems like I might be busy with other things -- https://www.shuvubanimint.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/מוקד-הישועות-באנר-חדש.jpg

Comment: (the phone numbers at the bottom are free numbers for Europe and US, left and right respectively)